# "Watch Your Step" isn't working

Tags: achievements, terraria

I have been hit by dart traps hundreds of times since 1.3, not to mention
boulder and bomb traps.

They were naturally generated, and on separate worlds and characters.

I have had no problem getting the other achievements (I haven't encountered any bugs), and yet I cannot seem to get this achievement (Watch Your Step).

How can I get the 'Watch your Step' achievement?

EDIT:
Okay, so funny story, the day after I posted this, I died to a plunger trap, and got the achivement! Go figure...

Comment: Funny story, but yes you have to die to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the achievement the trap you trigger needs to kill you, just getting hit by it isn't enough.

Comment: If you tried to get this achievement in Minecraft Hardcore... Well that was a fail

Comment: @PythonMaster I imagine trying to get *any* Terraria achievement in Minecraft would fail, but by all means feel free to correct me.

Comment: @tjd Terraria does have a hardcore mode of its own, so it may just have been a typo

Comment: No it isn't @JonK

Comment: @PythonMaster Ok, then I have no idea what Minecraft has to do with this...

Comment: It's just a joke @JonK